# CSS - Fill Space for Two Percentage-Width Columns with One Max-Width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So, it's been a while since I tackled web development and I can't seem to remember how to deal with this one. Hours of googling later, I'm more knowledgeable about flex-boxes and other neat tools, but none of the solutions are quite doing the trick yet.

What I want:

- Container A, which has two columns, Left and Right.
- Left Column is usually 25% width, Right column is usually 75% width.
- Right Column has max-width constraint, let's say 500px.
- When Right Column reaches its max-width, Left Column should fill up the remaining space so it isn't wasted.

I can't seem to get this to happen. I've tried flex settings on each with a flex-basis of 75% on the right column and "stretch" on the left; I've tried changing the display styles; I've even tried some overflow: hidden tricks (knowing full well they won't work out because I don't want to hide the overflow). So far, I'm only getting two variations - either both columns retain their initial sizing of 25% / 75%, or the left column stretches out behind the right column instead of taking up the available space.

I'm looking for a CSS solution to this if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.a {
    display: flex;
}

.left {
    flex: 1;
}

.right {
    flex: 3;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.left, .right {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="a">
   <div class="left">
   first
   </div>
   <div class="right">
   second
   </div>
  </div>
```

as `max-width: 500px` on `.right` in medium, big screen you cant see 75% width.

Comment: This is actually one of the first things I tried, but the flex in my code is being ignored. I'm testing now on my end to see what could be overriding it - is there something common like display or width/height inheritance that would take precedence?

Comment: Found it; something higher up in my code is cascading down to the inner divs and setting them to position: absolute. I unchecked that snippet in Chrome's developer tools and the divs position themselves correctly. Thank you!